# Use gpicview to scroll between all images in a directory using mouse or keyboard like arrows or pageup

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, image-processing, image-editor

With GPicView 0.2.3 and Lubuntu 13.04 running LXDE , the next/previous function never seems to work.  Keyboard shortcuts show that the arrow keys should move between next and previous images, but nothing happens.  Clicking on the GUI arrows does nothing.  Selecting multiple images on opening the program does not change the behavior.

I am working with a directory of ~2MB jpg images on the internal hard drive.  They were taken with an Android Nexus 4.

Opening single images works great, but each image must be opened individually.  This is quite frustrating.

Any ideas?  Alternative image browsers may be the solution.

`apt-cache policy gpicview` shows `Installed: 0.2.3+git20130101-0ubuntu1`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the files didn't have the proper suffix.  Although GPicView would successfully open the jpeg's even though they didn't have a .jpg or .jpeg extension -- it wouldn't navigate through them.

adding the `jpg` suffix to all the files  solved the problem.

For example

```
for f in * ; do mv -v -- "$f" "$f".jpg ; done
```

or

```
rename 's/$/.jpg/' *
```